# Text in svg is not wrapping around a box

Tags: text, wrap, svg, css

I am trying to include an sag image in Latex like the following.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includesvg[inkscapelatex=false, width=0.7\pdfpagewidth]{figure.svg}
\end{figure}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"...>
 <path d="M 610 300 L 610 363.63" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" />
        <path d="M 610 368.88 L 606.5 361.88 L 610 363.63 L 613.5 361.88 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all" />
        <path d="M 690 235 L 880 235 L 880 363.63" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke" />
        <path d="M 880 368.88 L 876.5 361.88 L 880 363.63 L 883.5 361.88 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all" />
        <path d="M 610 170 L 690 235 L 610 300 L 530 235 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all" />
        <g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)">
            <switch>
                <foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 400px; height: 1px; padding-top: 235px; margin-left: 531px;">
                        <div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; ">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">
                                <span style="color: rgb(26 , 26 , 26) ; font-family: &quot;opensans&quot; , &quot;arial&quot; , sans-serif , &quot;noto sans hebrew&quot; , &quot;noto sans&quot; , &quot;noto sans jp&quot; , &quot;noto sans kr&quot; ; background-color: rgba(255 , 255 , 255 , 0.01)">
                                    <font style="font-size: 12px">This is a very long text that should be wrapped inside the box.</font>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </foreignObject>
                <text x="610" y="239" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">This is a very long te.../text>
            </switch>
        </g>
</svg>
```

The problem that I have is in the image, the text is being cut off. Is there any way that this can be fixed? Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: First, your SVG file is broken, for example `version="1.1"...>`, the three dots don't belong there. Similarly, `.../text>` isn't a proper closing tag `</text>`.

And secondly, you specify `inkscapelatex=false` in the LaTeX file, which means LaTeX will not touch the text, so any wrapping you want to have should be done by the program generating the SVG file.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Thanks for the reply. The first `...` was meant to denote it continues. And for `.../text>` that is what I get while I download SVG from the program generating it and that is what is displayed in the image, the trailing ... 

In terms of `inkscapelatex=false`, the program I am creating SVG from has the wrapping fine. I can even see it in different browsers being perfectly wrapped. Only, when I import it in Overleaf, it is showing the trailing ... like shown above.

Comment: Well, it may be that is what you get, but it is wrong. So you must find a better way to export the SVG file, or get another program that does a better job of exporting it. After correcting the errors I mentioned, and putting the full text in the box, I imported it in Inkscape, let it wrap the text in the box, and used the corrected file in LaTeX and it just shows the text wrapped in the box. So this is not a LaTeX problem but a problem of your SVG generating program.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapped text is in this part of the SVG file:

```
<foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 400px; height: 1px; padding-top: 235px; margin-left: 531px;">
        <div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; ">
            <div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">
                <span style="color: rgb(26 , 26 , 26) ; font-family: &quot;opensans&quot; , &quot;arial&quot; , sans-serif , &quot;noto sans hebrew&quot; , &quot;noto sans&quot; , &quot;noto sans jp&quot; , &quot;noto sans kr&quot; ; background-color: rgba(255 , 255 , 255 , 0.01)">
                    <font style="font-size: 12px">This is a very long text that should be wrapped inside the box.</font>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</foreignObject>
```

"foreignObject" is, as the name suggests, not an SVG object. So it is not recognised by `inkscape` which has to do the conversion to PDF.

So you either have to do the wrapping in an Inkscape-compatible way (for example by `inkscape` itself), or you should export your image in PDF format in your drawing program.